# How to get PreviousTrackButton/NextTrackButton click event of MediaPlayerElement?

Tags: uwp, media-player

I'm using UWP `MediaPlayerElement`.

When playing videos, use may click next track button to view next video.

How to get `PreviousTrackButton`/`NextTrackButton` `Click` event of `MediaPlayerElement`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button click events are handled directly by the `MediaPlayerElement` and the events are not directly surfaced. However, you can customize the Media Transport Control which surfaces them and add the events manually. You can refer to [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls) for full instructions on customizing the default control behavior.

In this case you will want to override the `OnApplyTemplate` method and subscribe to the button events there using `GetTemplateChild` method:

```
 protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
 {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    var previousButton = GetTemplateChild("TheButtonName") as Button;
    previousButton.Click += PreviousTrackClicked;
}
```

Where *TheButtonName* is the name of the specific button as you find it in the default style's template.